# Define when an Isosceles Triangle, in 3-D Space, has its Base's Vertices' Averaged z-Value Equal to the z-Value of the Apex

Tags: geometry

For an isosceles triangle allowed to assume any configuration in a 3-D Cartesian coordinate system, how do you geometrically define the set of configurations in which the average value of the z-components of the base's vertices of the triangle is equal to the z-component of the apex?

So far the conditions I have thought of are:

1. All points reside in a plane parallel to the xy-plane.
2. If case #1 does not apply: if a plane exists which is perpendicular to the xy-plane, does not contain the coordinates of the base's vertices, has both base vertices on the same side of the plane, and the shortest distance between the assumed plane and a base vertex is the same distance for both base vertices in the triangle, and the apex must have a greater z-value than one of the base's vertices and a lower z-value than the other vertex on the base.

What I have stated above may be flawed, and even if it is not flawed I think that a much more succinct/formal definition exists.

Comment: How 'bout "the central axis (or "axis of symmetry") from apex to base is orthogonal to the $z$-axis"?

Comment: @JohnHughes I think that works. So far haven't thought of any way in which it wouldn't. Thank you!